# spring-rabbitmq does not respect replyTimeout for InOut Exchanges

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-amqp, spring-camel

I think I found a bug in the spring-rabbitmq component. It seems that the replyTimeout settings (neither path nor spring properties) will be accepted by the component. I have create a sample project for you to show the issue. The route is very simple:

```
    from("timer:hello?repeatCount=1")
        .transform(simple("Random number ${random(0,100)}"))
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                ">>>>>>> Timeout of replay should happen after 10 secs (application.properties) or 15 secs as " +
                        "here configured")
        .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "spring-rabbitmq:foo?routingKey=mykey&replyTimeout=15000");
```

I expect that the listener will throw a "Reply timed out" AmqpReplyTimeoutException after 15 seconds (or 10 seconds as defined in the application.properties). What is happening:

[image]

You see that after 30 secs the exception occurred. It seems that we are hitting here the default configurations of Spring AMQ instead the setup configurations.

[image]